# Any Available datasets for Hydroponic / Aquaponic /Aeroponic?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, classification, agriculture, hydrology

I'm working on a research project for developing predictive models for hydro-/aqua-/aeroponics. Where can I found related datasets for the nutrients and other sensitive parameters?

The specific idea of the project is not defined yet, I will set it according to the available datasets.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently developing Veleda, an open source, open data platform for hydroponics. We have a [live data view](https://data.veleda.io/dashboard/db/growtower?orgId=1) of the state in our greenhouses. We develop the software and hardware (ESP8266) behind it and are in the process of extending it with additional parameters.

Parameters for which we are building low-cost sensors range from air and water temperature to pH and EC values, from biomass to image derived plant health. The server side source code is available on the [Github](https://github.com/FlowLeafLab/veleda) page and we will be releasing the hardware in the coming weeks.

The project is based in the [Protohaus](http://sdg.protohaus.org/) and sponsored by the city of Brunswick.

Comment: so does the serverside source code have datasets?

Comment: The source code and datasets are separated. The code is on Github, the datasets on data.veleda.io. The first batch of plants are currently germinating, which means that meaningful data will be available in a few months

Comment: ah, maybe point out what live view is more specifically. sorry for the questions

Comment: What data types (biomass/temperature/pH) are you interested in?

Comment: i'm not, the question is asking for them.

Comment: Live view means the live data feed from the greenhouse. How would you formulate that? The data can also be downloaded

Comment: i would say what live view means....i thought it was a video feed